# ReadOnlyCollection duplicates in loop

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

I have a method, which get data from external resource, add it to ReadOnlyCollection and return this collection:

```
    public ReadOnlyCollection<TransactionDto> GetTransactions(int carrierId, DateTime beginDate, DateTime? endDate = null)
    {
        // call an external resource and save result to resultArray
        return _mapper.Map<ReadOnlyCollection<TransactionDto>>(resultArray);
    }
```

my another method:

```
    public List<string> Run(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        List<string> transactionsJson = new List<string>();
        foreach (var carrierId in carrierIds)
        {
            var transactions = efsService.GetTransactions(
                carrierId, startDate, endDate);

            if (transactions.Count > 0)
            {
                var transactionJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transactions);
                transactionsJson.Add(transactionJson);
            }
        }
        return transactionsJson;
    }
```

problem is if method GetTransactions returns records for some carrierId, this variable of `ReadOnlyCollection` type will returned for rest carrierId in the loop. It's like cached data. Why so happened?

**Added:**

mapper is declared in ctor of my class:

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperTransactionProfile>());
        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

AutoMapperTransactionProfile declaration:

```
internal class AutoMapperTransactionProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperTransactionProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<WSTransaction, TransactionDto>();
        CreateMap<WSTransactionInfo, TransactionInfoDto>();
        CreateMap<WSTransactionLineItem, TransactionLineItemDto>();
    }
}
```

only one instance of `_mapper` is used in loop

Comment: Do you mean, Run method should return only one carrierId's transaction records at a time ?

Comment: @MilanRaval yes, like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove for-loop from method, and call extenrnal resource to get transaction details only once. like below...

```
public List<string> Run(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int carrierId)
    {
        List<string> transactionsJson = new List<string>();

            var transactions = efsService.GetTransactions(
                carrierId, startDate, endDate);

            if (transactions.Count > 0)
            {
                var transactionJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transactions);
                transactionsJson.Add(transactionJson);
            }

        return transactionsJson;
    }
```

**Update:**

I have mocked your code without mapper, it is not returning records of previous carrierId. Still not clear about how you have declared your class, and how you mapped it. To me it looks like some problem in your mapper or the service that is returning records from previous carrierId.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadOnlyCollection
{
    class Program
    {

        static List<Tuple<int, string>> transactions = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "1"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "11"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "2"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "12"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "3"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "13"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(4, "4"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(5, "5"));
            transactions.Add(Tuple.Create(6, "6"));

            Run(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
        }

        public static List<string> Run(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var carrierIds = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6};

            List<string> transactionsJson = new List<string>();
            foreach (var carrierId in carrierIds)
            {
                var transactions = GetTransactions(
                    carrierId, startDate, endDate);

                if (transactions.Count > 0)
                {
                    var transactionJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transactions);
                    transactionsJson.Add(transactionJson);
                }
            }
            return transactionsJson;
        }

        public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetTransactions(int carrierId, DateTime beginDate, DateTime? endDate = null)
        {
            // call an external resource and save result to resultArray
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(transactions.Where(item => item.Item1 == carrierId).Select(item => item.Item2).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is difference? Loop will be outside this method

Comment: Oh ok, is your resultArray returning proper result. Like only transactions for the carrierId ? then may be _mapper has something that is caching it.

Comment: caching on AutoMapper level? Hmm, probably... But, in any case, loop in outside method could not solve problem....

Comment: @OlegSh: You are right, one thing worth trying is, populate simple list using mapper, and return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(list);. Does your mapper has any static+custom implementation ?

Comment: added to main post

Comment: @OlegSh: Updated answer